# What is the common word for the cover of the pot-cooking?

Tags: word-choice

When referring to something that covers another things, normally there are 3 words:

> - cover
> - lid
> - top

My question refers to the cover of a pot. What is the usual word for that in English? (I don't want to be weird and refer it in a word that is not normally for that).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Lid.

The other two are easily understood but not used for pots and pans.  "Cover" might be something soft or not fitted to the pot. "Top" would potentially be used to refer to a piece of a cooking tool that is not a pot, like maybe a kettle.